# Error with success condition ajax on phonegap

Tags: php, android, mysql, ajax, cordova

I'm trying to create a login and registration app, but there was a problem. When I'm click the button the alert showed was exchange with another alert condition.

This is my code

```
$("#regis").click(function() {
                var nama = $("#namalengkap").val();
                var noid = $("#noid").val();
                var username = $("#uname").val();
                var password = $("#pwd").val();
                var email = $("#email").val();
                var ttl = $("#ttl").val();
                var alamat = $("#alamat").val();
                var jk = $("#gender").val();
                var dataString = "namalengkap=" + nama + "&noid=" + noid + "&uname=" + username + "&pwd=" + password + "&email=" + email + "&ttl=" + ttl + "&alamat=" + alamat + "&gender=" + jk + "&regis=";
                if ($.trim(nama).length > 0 & $.trim(noid).length > 0 & $.trim(username).length > 0 & $.trim(password).length > 0 & $.trim(email).length > 0 & $.trim(ttl).length > 0 & $.trim(alamat).length > 0 & $.trim(jk).length > 0)
                {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "http://localhost/JsEx/www/php/regis.php",
                        data: dataString,
                        crossDomain: true,
                        cache: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data=="success"){
                                alert("Registration Complete");
                            }
                            else {
                                alert("registration Failed");
                                window.location.reload();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                return false;
            });
```

the alert was showed when I'm finished the registration was alert in else , but the data was inserted to the database.

When I'm click the button

[image: [1]]

In the database

[image: [2]]

Comment: can you show your regis.php file? And please alert first data variable above the if condition where you have to check data gives "success" string or other error message from message.

Comment: F12, what do you see in console and network when you make the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

working code ...

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://localhost/JsEx/www/php/regis.php",
          data: dataString,
          crossDomain: true,
          cache: false,
          success: function(){
             alert("Registration Complete");
          },
          error: function(){
            alert("registration Failed");
            window.location.reload();
          }
      });
```

for more ref check.  https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/